# How to fully auto boot CentOS 7 Rescue Mode (Building Custom ISO)

Tags: centos, iso-image, rescue

I am building a custom CentOS 7 iso. I want the iso to fully boot into "Rescue Mode" without any user intervention. My goal is to use the finished "Rescue Mode" iso to boot VM's (kvm QEMU environment) and fix stuff, be able to connect via ssh, etc. In other words, rescue data on a very broken server.

I edited the isolinux.cfg on the iso to automatically "select" and boot "Rescue Mode". However, after that, I am still prompted to enter a number (1,2,3,4) in order to perform an action (mount / not mount any existing OS, reboot, etc.) and then press "enter" to return to the shell.

How can I bypass this? I want to get into the shell after my VM is booted from the iso.

Boot Rescue Mode:

[image: Boot screenshot for clarity]

To clarify, I am able to extract, work with the squash image and generate a new working iso.

Comment: Start with a bootable CentOS7 Live ISO or even a rescue (knoppix, etc) ISO and modify the contents of its root filesystem to include the tools you want. Tools that manipulate squashfs and similar will let you populate your toolbox as you wish.

Comment: @stolenmoment Hello, and thanks for commenting. I am actually able to add new content to the ISO and build it (Extract ISO -> Edit squash image -> Generate new ISO). I am currently trying to figure out how to configure the iso, so that when in boots, I get into the shell instantly, without keyboard input. Sorry if my question / description was not clear enough. Will update my post.

Comment: The thing to do is to set up a systemd default state which runs a shell on the console.  I think that /usr/lib/systemd/system/debug-shell.service would be a great place to start, it may even be all you need.  As a first try, configure your systemd with debug-shell as its default target and see how far you get. I can't tell you specifics, I'd have to try it out myself, but that should get you going.  Learning how to deal with systemd will do you well.  Hmm.. debug-shell can't be isolated.  Experiment with that and you'll learn a lot!